# Getting a random value of enum and saving to pointer struct

Tags: c

Hey guys I can only find c++ examples of using rand() on an enum. I want to get a random color from my enum either white or red, and then give the thiscolor variable in the struct player the color.

I have so far got this-

```
enum cell_contents
{
/** the cell does not contain a token **/
C_EMPTY, 
/** the cell contains a red token **/
C_RED, 
/** the cell contains a white token **/
C_WHITE
};

typedef enum cell_contents color;
```

Then I have a struct -

```
struct player
{
/**
 * the player's name
 **/
char name[NAMELEN+2];
/**
 * the color of the token for the player. Note: this is a typedef of 
 * enum @ref cell_contents.
 **/
color thiscolor;
/**
 * how many counters does this player have on the board? 
 **/
unsigned counters;
/**
 * what type of player is this? A human or a computer? 
 **/
enum playertype type;
};
```

Then in a function that initialises all the values in the struct i have

```
enum input_result get_human_player(struct player* human)
{ 
human->thiscolor = color(rand() % 2);
}
```

However it just gives me an error saying "unexpected type name 'color' : expected expression". I also tried to just use:

```
human->thiscolor = enum cell_contents(rand() % 2);
```

also

```
human->thiscolor = enum color(rand() % 2);
```

but both of these also did not work?

Comment: Note that `x % 2` results in `0` or `1` given `x` is of type `int`. Seeing how you have 3 colors you might be looking for `rand() % 3`.

Comment: The first 2 are colours but the third one is denoting an empty spot

Comment: I see you have `CELL_EMPTY, CELL_WHITE, CELL_RED`. `0` would correspond to `CELL_EMPTY`, which you seem to not want. So either do `(rand() % 2) + 1` or switch up the order in your `enum` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

`color` is a *type* (or rather a type-alias), and can't be used like a function. I think you're mixing in some other language in your C code (maybe C++?)

In C any `int` is implicitly convertible to an enum, so just doing e.g.

```
human->thiscolor = rand() % 2;
```

should work fine.

If want to explicitly cast the integer to the `color` type, then do

```
human->thiscolor = (color) (rand() % 2);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was using examples from C++ as I couldn't find any C examples online, that works perfectly!